# SalesforceMobileSDK-Android v10.2.0 crashing on Android 11 devices

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-android

The SalesforceMobileSDK-Android v10.2.0 is crashing on Android 11 devices with the below error message:

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.salesforce.androidsdk.accounts.UserAccount.getUserLevelFilenameSuffix()' on a null object reference`

The last working version for Android 11 devices is SalesforceMobileSDK-Android v9.1.1 but this SDK version is targeted to Android 11 and won't compile on projects with TargetSDK as 32. Post v9.1.1 all the SDK release up to v10.2.0 is crashing on Android 11 devices with the above logs.

Please help me with an SDK version which will compile to Android 12 and also work on Android 11 devices.

Comment: Hi Ankur,

Are there any additional logs or details about your configuration that may be relevant?  We have many customers using Android 11+ but this is the first report of this crash (seemingly from the account not being created).

Comment: Also, Mobile SDK 10.2 already targets and compiles against API 32, the second Android 12 API level.

Comment: @BrandonPage Thanks for the comment. We were able to identify the issue for Android 11 devices and were able to fix it by adding Proguard rules for the Salesforce SDK. However, we are encountering other issues as well related to SalesforceMobileSDK-Android v10.2.0. Please have a look at [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/394383/126983)